# The UISearchBar doesn't dismiss the keyboard when enter is pressed

Tags: objective-c, ios

The `UISearchBar` doesn't dismiss the keyboard when enter is pressed, or the user touch somewhere else.

I need to use the remove keyboard button on the bottom right of the iOS keyboard in order to remove the keyboard and invoke:

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)aSearchBar
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: have u set the delegate to self for the UISearchBar?

Comment: Agree with samfisher. The method you mention is supposed to be called by the search bar itself. But it requires its delegate to be set.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)aSearchBar {
    [aSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Also you have to set delegate for the UISearchBar: **UISearchBarDelegate**

It should work.

Here is sample code http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ToolbarSearch/Listings/ToolbarSearch_APLToolbarSearchViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009461-ToolbarSearch_APLToolbarSearchViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_9

Another option is searchBarSearchButtonClicked we can use.

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    // You can write search code Here
}
```

Comment: This dismisses the keyboard when the user tries to type! Should read searchBarTextDidEndEditing? searchBarSearchButtonClicked is a better solution

Comment: this prevents the user from being able to type in the search bar at all.

Comment: Thanks JulianB for suggestion, searchBarSearchButtonClicked

Answer (score 12):

Add **UISearchBarDelegate** in .h

Also **set SearchBar's object delegate to self**.

you should do add `UISearchBarDelegate`'s method:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    // Do the search...
}
```

**EDIT :** Above doesnot work then add this:

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Answer (score 3):

for swift 1.2 keyboard will hide when you click finished , and there is another function for cancel but it's not good to use it as when the user click cancel he might want to search for another word ...

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code snippet to close/hide the keyboard when return button is clicked.

```
- (BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text 
{

    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
    {        
        [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }
        return YES;
}
```

Comment: This won't work as the UISearchBar's return key can only be Search, and if the search text is empty, the Search return key is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

it will work -

objective c -

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder]; 
}
```

Swift -

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }
```